# Python 3 POST request to handle form data

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I can't figure out how to correctly set up a POST request with the following data:

```
General
Request URL: https://myurl.com/install/index.cgi
Request Method: POST

Request Headers
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 48
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: myurl.com
Origin: https://myurl.com
Referer: https://myurl.com/install/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)

Form Data
page: install
state: STATUS
```

I can do the following:

```
import requests

headers = {"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate,br",
    "Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "Cache-Control":"max-age=0",
    "Connection":"keep-alive",
    "Content-Length":"48",
    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Host":"myurl.com",
    "Origin":"https://myurl.com",
    "Referer":"https://myurl.com/install/?s=ROM",
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"}

f = requests.put(path, headers=headers)
```

But how do I handle the form data? Under the form data there is a page: install and a state: STATUS.

How do I include this on my POST request?

Comment: What have you done so far? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: by the way, why are you using `PUT` in the actual request if `Request Method: POST`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [add](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) `data=` to your request:

```py
import requests

path = ...
headers = ...
form_data = {
    "page": "install",
    "state": "STATUS",
}

f = requests.put(path, headers=headers, data=form_data)
```

Answer (score -1):

I presume you know how to use the developer tools on the browser of your choice.

The following is a template I follow:

Load the page (GET)

Use XPATH to find_element_by_id I'm targeting, i.e. username

Set XPATH to SetValue of such element

Post the page (POST)

Comment: that does not answer the question